# Frame work for jquery

Tags: jquery, frameworks

Does anybody know a framework for jQuery?? If one exists for front-end and back-end.
I would really appreciate an answer because I'm new on this.
Thanks.

Comment: A *framework* that does what exactly?

Comment: backend or frontend framework?

Comment: Why not framework for framework for framework for jquery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides that JQuery is in itself a Javascript framework, here are some frameworks *using* JQuery

**Front end framework :**

- [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

**Back end frameworks :**

- [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) + ZendX ([JQuery](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.html))
- [Code Igniter](http://codeigniter.com/) (read the [wiki](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/jQuery/) for JQuery)
- .Net (yes, it's a framework, C# is a language) - (read some [tutorials](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/Using-jQuery-with-ASP-NET.aspx))

**Other projects :**

- [GWTQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) ([Google I/O 2009](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sl5em1UPuoI&feature=player_embedded))

Answer (score 0):

If you need a jQuery / jQuery UI integrated backend framework, then http://agiletoolkit.org does that. It goes few steps ahead than Zend, CI, and others. Objects are being JS-aware. Good demo here:

http://agiletoolkit.org/intro/javascript

For a front-end certainly jQuery UI.